# mercurial copying an existing branch

Tags: mercurial

We have 3 branches, default bugfix and release.

After some bad merges bugfix is now in a very broken state. We've kind of ignored this branch for a while but now it's needed again. I'd like it to be exactly like default but merging doesn't work, because it now has the same ancestor as default.

I've tried to just copypaste default branch to bugfix branch, and commit that.

That seems to work in the sense that

```
hg up --rev commitB
hg diff --rev commitA
```

hg diff gives back nothing, and

```
hg up --rev commitA
hg diff --rev commitB
```

hg diff gives back nothing

but when I hg up from one commit to the other I still see "42 files updated" which makes me think there are differences...

How can I know for sure that there aren't any differences? and if there are how do I make the branches identical?

Comment: are those 2 commit in the same branch ? does the following command show anything ? `hg diff -r commitA -r commitB`

Comment: They are not in the same branch, and that commit gives back nothing

Comment: could you post the result of `hg glog -l5` (Note: it's a L lower case and the number can be increased to go further back in history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches are more fluid than you're imaging them.  When you talk about what is in branch X what you're really saying is "what the working directory looks like if I check out the most recent (technically tipward) commit whose branch: label is set to X.

So, if I'm understanding what you want your easiest solution is to just create a new (and thus most recent) commit with the branch name `bugfix`.  This should do that:

```
hg update default
hg branch --force bugfix
...make a tiny change (perhaps to the readme)...
hg commit -m 'reinvogorating bugfix'
```

Then when you `hg update bugfix` it will be exactly like `deafult` was at the time you did that.

What you're doing isn't working because files that have been removed and/or added in default  weren't removed or added in your bugfix via copypaste, but reallly don't copy paste, just re-create bugfix off of default and be done with it.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer what I was looking for :) What would happen to the old head of bugfix? would it just be an head and thats it?

Comment: It would still be a head.  If you wanted it gone you could `hg update bugfix ; hg commit --close-branch` on it before doing the steps above, or you could merge it in and select nothing from it, but neither is necessary.  Every place you reference `bugfix` will always get the most tipward one.

Comment: I think ill merge it, so the head dissappears and then do the routine in your answer, thanks!